# how to display data in table panel dynamically

Tags: sql-server

I am working on one windows application in C#.In that,there is one form in which i want to display category wise book images in table layout panel.And for each category I want to display 5 book images.

the query I use to retrieve category wise book is

```
WITH CategoryCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        BookName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CategoryName
            ORDER BY CategoryName DESC
        ) AS CTE_Order
    FROM BookMaster
)
SELECT bm.BookName,bm.BookImage, cm.CategoryName, scm.SubCategoryName
FROM 
    CategoryCTE 
    INNER JOIN BookMaster bm ON CategoryCTE.BookName = bm.BookName
    INNER JOIN CategoryMaster cm ON bm.CategoryName = cm.Oid
    INNER JOIN SubCategoryMaster scm ON bm.SubCategoryName = scm.Oid
WHERE CategoryCTE.CTE_Order < 6
GROUP BY cm.CategoryName, scm.SubCategoryName, bm.BookName,bm.BookImage
```

this query gives me proper output i.e it gives me 5 books from each category.
But the problem is,I want to display book images in table panel i.e.row 1 will have 5 book images of category 1,row 2 have book images of category 2 and so on.Now I am having 4 book categories in my database.That means table layout panel's rows  depend on category table in database,and column of tables are fixed i.e first column is category name and other 5 column have book images.

I hope I have explained my question properly.Please suggest me any solution for this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: could you add an example of result set you want to produce in SQL ? (and ideally a sqlfiddle with data and structure :) )

Comment: the query which I have given above gives result like

Comment: above query gives me proper output,my problem is to how to display it in table panel layout

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to look something like:

```
CategoryName   Book1         Book2             Book3           Book4          Book5
------------   -----------   ---------------   --------------  -------------  ------------
Cat1           Image#6.jpg   Image#61.jpg      Image#62.jpg    Image#63.jpg   Image#64.jpg
Cat2           Image#5.jpg   Image#51316.jpg   Image#5136.jpg  Image#516.jpg  Image#56.jpg
```

The following query should do it:

```
WITH CategoryCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        BookName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CategoryName
            ORDER BY CategoryName DESC, BookName
        ) AS CTE_Order
    FROM BookMaster    
)

SELECT CategoryName, [1] AS Book1, [2] AS Book2, [3] AS Book3, [4] AS Book4, [5] AS Book5
FROM 
(SELECT bm.BookImage, cm.CategoryName, c.CTE_Order FROM 
    CategoryCTE c
    INNER JOIN BookMaster bm ON c.BookName = bm.BookName
    INNER JOIN CategoryMaster cm ON bm.CategoryName = cm.Oid
    INNER JOIN SubCategoryMaster scm ON bm.SubCategoryName = scm.Oid
WHERE c.CTE_Order < 6
GROUP BY cm.CategoryName, bm.BookImage, c.CTE_Order
) Sub
PIVOT (MAX(BookImage) FOR CTE_Order IN ([1],[2],[3], [4],[5])) AS PivotTable
```